# All browers fail, when there is internet connectivity

Tags: windows-xp, browser, troubleshooting

This may not be the correct forum but I hope somebody may be able to help me troubleshoot an issue I,ve had for the past 2 weeks. I'm running an Windows XP SP3 machine and at least once a day, my browser stops working. It will slowly load but does not show an error or the page itself. This is the same across I.E, Chrome and Firefox.

However If I ping a site say "www.google.com", I get a response from the server. The issue is resolved after I restart my desktop. I've had no issue on my other devices but that said I use my xp machine the most.

I've tried the following:

1. swapping out the Ethernet cable in case it is faulty but still no change.
2. netstat command but dont see any out of the ordinary programs
   running
3. netsh winsock reset command but no change
4. Virus scan but no threats found.

I am at a complete loss so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

*Additional Information that may or may not be relevant;

- I noticed that spotify works normally however dropbox does not.
- I notice the broswer failure almost always occurs when watching
  youtube. Ive been watching a lot lately as I have been following tutorials.

Comment: Can you verify that you can reach the internet (or not) when the browsers stop working? E.g. use ping, traceroute, ssh, telnet, whatever except a browser.

Comment: yes, I can ping sites outside my local network

Comment: Are your browsers configured to use a proxy?

Comment: No, just a standard setup

Comment: what task manager says? (process,network..) ? Have you tried to turn off security in internet options?

Comment: Unfortunately I've restarted the machine so more than likely the issue wont arise for another few hours again.

Comment: Ok its happened again very quickly; Firefox.exe(114,568k mem usage)- running normally. Network Utilization 0% with an occasional spike of 0.01/0.02%. The browers closes fine without any warings or errors. Earlier I had switched off all firewalls with no effect

Comment: Does it happen at the same time every day?  What ISP and router are you using?  When it happens, have you tried doing an ipconfig/flushdns?  I actually have a similar issue at work, every afternoon about 1-2pm, I suddenly can't access certain specific sites (Superuser being one) while others work perfectly fine.  I've always suspected a routing issue...  Today I plan to try flushing the DNS to see if it helps :)

Comment: I also tried dns flush but to no avail. At first I suspected it was a certain time of day but then it seems to occur every few hours. It may have something to do with the length of time I using the browser. Also all webpages are affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen issues similar to this before.  Last time, it turned out to be a corrupted TCP/IP stack that allowed some traffic through, but gave fits to other traffic.  You might try resetting it per the instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I implemented your answer and after a few days I haven't had an issue since. Thanks again.

Comment: @Calgar99 Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

there might be cookies problem for browsers
try Shift+Ctrl+Del

or

reset internet setting
1.search for internet options in search programs(from start button)
2.goto advanced tab and reset internet settings!

Comment: Hi Peter, Im afraid your suggested approach has had no affect.